# Mouse Hover action in C# Selenium webdriver

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

I'm newbie to C# Selenium. I tried to automate an "sign in" and "sign out" of an LinkedIn Application. For that I have written the below code,

Here the "Sign out" is an hidden element.

**My code**

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.linkedin.com/");
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-email")).SendKeys("valid email ID");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-password")).SendKeys("valid password");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit")).Click();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='img-defer-id-1-6775']"))).Build().Perform(); // Getting an exception here
Thread.Sleep(3000);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='account-sub-nav']/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/span/span[3]/a")).Click();
```

But I'm getting an "No Such Element Exception". Even I tried to find the element by ID  but getting the same exception. Not sure what I did wrong.

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 5):

Hoverable elements I find it's best to use JavaScript.  Action Builder tends to have a high rate of failure, and will cause other hoverable elements to become visible as it scrolls through the page, causing the element that you want to become obscured.  I've found this method somewhere online (can't remember where) and it works significantly better than any other method I've tried.

```
String javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
                "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
                "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";


IJavaScriptExecutor executor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
executor.ExecuteScript(javaScript, webElement);
```

Comment: Thank you. The Selenium MoveToElement( by element ).Build().Perform() functions was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a Thread.sleep after clicking submit button.
Here issue is selenium driver is searching for element even before page is loaded.Hence element not found exception is thrown.

Instead of Thread.sleep in your code ,you could use explicit waits.

Try this

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.linkedin.com/");
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-email")).SendKeys("valid email ID");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("login-password")).SendKeys("valid password");
driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit")).Click();
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='img-defer-id-1-6775']")));
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='img-defer-id-1-6775']"))).Build().Perform(); 
 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='account-sub-nav']/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/span/span[3]/a"))).Click();
```

Comment: Explicit wait will wait for maximum of 60 sec in this case.if element is not found until then ,element not found exception is thrown. If element is found within 60 seconds then it will continue with execution.

Answer (score 0):

If the element you are trying to click is invisible, you can make it visible trough JavaScript and then click on it:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("THE ELEMENT YOU WANT TO CLICK.hidden = false;", element);
element.click
```

Comment: If you are trying to execute a user scenario, you don't want to use the JSE to make elements visible. Approach the scenario as a user would. What would the user need to do to complete the scenario? Script that and the necessary elements will become visible and you will be able to interact with them. If you use JSE to make elements visible, you aren't testing user scenarios... but maybe it's not necessary to the OP.

Comment: he says that he is "trying to automate", so I don't think it will be a problem to make the element visible just to complete the task